# How to add multiple php variables in environment variable i.e path

Tags: php, apache

Well, I have previously installed PHP 5.3.28 from executable which installed it on my machine, globally with entries in the path variable as:

```
path ...;C:\php\php53\;...
```

and another variable as:

```
PHPRC C:\php\php53
```

This PHP is configured with Apache 2.2.Running PHP -v from command line results in the version of PHP

[image]

After some time I needed to upgrade my versions of PHP (to 5.6) and Apache (to 2.4) and I downloaded them as archived packages and configured them. So now I have two separately configured sets of PHP and Apache.
Both of them are working fine, and i also added new PHP 5.6 into my environmental variables but it is not recognizing it.

[image]

My environmental variables are:

[image]

I also added C:\php\php56\ to path also ahead of red line.But its not working.I require both of these versions of php.exe's.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have php56.exe present in "c:\php\php56\"  i.e. "c:\php\php56\php56.exe".  You can rename php.exe to php56.exe to test.

Have you also restarted you cmd prompt?  Environment variables (the path) do no update inside of an active cmd prompt unless they are edited only within the command prompt.

You can also try calling c:\php\php56\php.exe with a full path to make certain it is working regardless of paths.

Comment: That is what I was missing. Renaming php.exe as their specific versions solved this issue now I can invoke different versions just by calling their name like php53, php56 and php7.Absolute path was working before i just wanted to use a short name for them. Thanks anyways, it helped.